# run WSO2 CEP in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, wso2, wso2-cep

How can I run WSO2 CEP in eclipse IDE so I can get all the logs in the Eclipse console?

I searched online and no guidance is provided. Although, I have been able to create extensions for WSO2 CEP I was not able to run WSO2 CEP as a whole in eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running the entire CEP product on an IDE is not practical as it's a large collection of bundles which come from several git projects. However you can remote debug any component you need by providing the `-debug <port>` option when you start the product and connecting the IDE on that port.

If you are looking to run only the Siddhi engine, it's possible and you can clone the code, maven build and run/debug on IDE.