# How can i run wso2 api-manager source code in IntelliJ IDEA or eclise?

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I am using wso2 API Manager. I want to run source code by idea or eclipse , how can do this?
I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [run WSO2 CEP in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42366062/run-wso2-cep-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

You need to clone [1] and [2].

You can debug as in [3]

1. https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt
2. https://github.com/wso2/product-apim
3. https://anuradha-15.medium.com/remote-debugging-wso2-products-using-intellij-idea-ide-c0e828abd700

Comment: I am using API manager, it's version is 4.0.0,  so which branch of carbon-apimgt and product-apim is right for me?  It's default branch is master,  should I switch to another branch instead?

Comment: This is the tag - https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt/tree/v9.0.174
https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/tree/v4.0.0

Comment: How to debug locally?